# PHP7 - optimize images ( Compress without losing quality )

Tags: php, image, compression

I have a problem with my project. I want to optimize images on it. I tried to convert images to .webp, but I found that it not supported by browsers.

When I test my website on PageSpeedInsight of Google, it's given me warning about images and I need to compress them. and at the same time, he gives me the new compress picture, perfectly and with small size.

But I try to do that with PHP, but I can't get the same result of google page Insight.

Message from pageSpeedInsight:

> Image formats like JPEG 2000, JPEG XR, and WebP often provide better
>   compression than PNG or JPEG, which means faster downloads and less
>   data consumption

Is there any best solution to optimize images? I use a native PHP framework (MVC).

Comment: Convert them to jpgs.

Comment: @bassxzero, I try it but still the problem, all my pictures on the website are jpg, and always I get this alert

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) library, to convert your images to WEBP format.

And use .htaccess to show the webp images when server supports, cuz not all browsers support WEBP images. In this case, you must have a copy of the image in other common extension (jpg, png) and you can compress with [tinypng API.](https://tinypng.com/developers)

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    # Vary: Accept for all the requests to jpeg and png
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(jpe?g|png)$" REQUEST_image
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Check if browser supports WebP images
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

    # Check if WebP replacement image exists
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

    # Serve WebP image instead
    RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary Accept env=REQUEST_image
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `not all browsers support WEBP images` - which is unfortunate.  I been waiting for that for a very long time.  WEBP is like a mix of JPG and PNG.  Uses better compression and has transparency.  Maybe it will be ready by the end of 2020 lol ... one can hope.  Then we can get rid of all those legacy formats.  If I recall it also supports animation frames.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yeah. Is quite inconvenient, but I believe only Chrome supports WEBP.

Comment: yea it's part of Googles V8 stuff.  It's not without it's issues too (I read stuff the the quality vs compression rate can be worse then JPG in some cases).  But at some point they need to just due away with all those old formats.